# MSSQL 2008R2 Avoid Repeated Items in Matrix Like Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, matrix

I tried to find solutions for this and it is somehow easy to solve when records are below a certain number. But...

I have an original list with 81,590 records.

```
Id  Loc Sales   LatLong
1   a   100 ...
2   b   110 ...
3   c   105 ...
4   d   125 ...
5   e   123 ...
6   f   35  ...
.
.
.
81,590  ... ... ...
```

I need to compare all items in the list against each other.

```
    Id  L1  L2  Dist    
    1   a   a   0   --> Not needed. Self comparison.
    2   a   b   26  
    3   a   c   150 --> Not needed. Distance >100.
    4   a   d   58  
    5   b   a   26  --> Not needed. Repeated record.
    6   b   b   0   --> Not needed. Self comparison.
    7   b   c   15  
    8   b   d   151 --> Not needed. Distance >100.
    9   c   a   150 --> Not needed. Repeated record.
    10  c   b   15  --> Not needed. Repeated record.
    11  c   c   0   --> Not needed. Self comparison.
    12  c   d   75  
    13  d   a   58  --> Not needed. Repeated record.
    14  d   b   151 --> Not needed. Repeated record.
    15  d   c   75  --> Not needed. Repeated record.
    16  d   d   0   --> Not needed. Self comparison.
```

But as shown next to the records above, the end result needs to be a list that:

1) Compares records against each other ONLY when they are located at a certain distance, say <100 miles.

2) Does not contain duplicates in the sense that comparing Loc1 to Loc2 is the same as comparing Loc2 to Loc1.

3) And the obvious one, no need to compare Loc1 to itself.

The end result would be:

```
    Id  L1  L2  Dist
    2   a   b   26
    4   a   d   58
    7   b   c   15
    12  c   d   75
```

Approach:

In theory, the total number of records after comparing all items against themselves is 81,590 ^ 2 = 6,656,928,100 records.

Subtracting repeated iterations (LocA-LocB = LocB-LocA) would mean 6,656,928,100 / 2 = 3,328,464,050.

Further cleaning by getting rid of self-repeating iterations (LocA-LocA), should be 3,328,464,050 - 81,590 = 3,328,382,460.

Then I could get rid of all records with distance > 100 miles.

This is highly inefficient, I'd be building a table with 6Bn records, then deleting half, etc. etc. etc.

---

Is there an approach to arrive to the end product in a much more efficient (less steps, less select/delete/update) way?

What is the select statement needed to insert the final data-set into destination?

It sounds to me like there is a join of the table with itself and a filtering by iterations of the key but here is where I am stuck.

Comment: Wat? You have data, needing to compare stuff based on distances but how do you know when it can match? Is it entirely distance based? I'm afraid in anonymizing your problem, you've obscured the useful bits

Comment: Yes, it is entirely on distance. I am using economic census data wanting to compare levels of sales of localities against other localities < 100 away.

Comment: Kansas City MO spends 30. Columbia spends 10. StL spends 1000 and are all over 100 miles away from each other. Expected output would show what? Kansas City->Columbia 30:10, KC->StL 30:1000 or KC->Columbia, KC->StL, Columbia->StL. In othe words, are you trying to generate the results for the whole domain or find all the locations from a central point?

Comment: Also, what does your table structure look like? SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012, 2014?

Comment: Good comments, @billinkc. I added more details and a couple of more examples as part of the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What algorithm are you using to calculate distance between two points? Simple “the world is flat” cartesian math, or that trigonometry-laden “the word is an oblate spherloid” one? This can turn into serious CPU requirements.

It’s probably best to generate a table of “locations that are within distance X of this location” once and store it permanently; barring major events like earthquakes, it’s just not going to change.

Query-wise, the base join is trivial:

```
SELECT
   t1.Loc L1
  ,t2.Loc L2
 from MyTable t1
  inner join MyTable t2
   on t2.Loc > t1.Loc
```

If have the distance formula in, say, a function named “distanceFunction”, it might look something like:

```
WITH cteCalc as (
    select
       t1.Loc L1
      ,t2.Loc L2
      ,dbo.distanceFunction(t1.LatLong, t2.LatLong) Dist
     from MyTable t1
      inner join MyTable t2
       on t2.Loc > t1.Loc
     where dbo.distanceFunction(t1.LatLong, t2.LatLong) < @MaxDistance)
 INSERT TargetTable (L1, L2, Dist)
 SELECT
    L1
   ,L2
   ,Dist
  where Dist <= @MaxDistance
```

This, of course, may break your system, if only because the transaction log will grow too big while you’re writing a few billion rows to the target table. I'd say build a loop, processing each location in turn, with the final query like:

```
WITH cteCalc as (
    select
       t1.Loc L1
      ,t2.Loc L2
      ,dbo.distanceFunction(t1.LatLong, t2.LatLong) Dist
     from MyTable t1
      inner join MyTable t2
       on t2.Loc > t1.Loc
     where dbo.distanceFunction(t1.LatLong, t2.LatLong) < @MaxDistance
      and t1.Loc = @ThisIterationLoc)
 INSERT TargetTable (L1, L2, Dist)
 SELECT
    L1
   ,L2
   ,Dist
  where Dist <= @MaxDistance
```

First pass returns 81,589 less whichever are too far away, second pass as 81,588 to process, and so forth.

Comment: Without additional data or clever tricks, you're going to have to match every row with every other row and calculate the distance. Yuk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of how I would solve this problem:

1. Put indexes on latitude and longitude
2. Do the math for lat and long of your distance for the range (box) of your distance.  Then you know that your distance (as box not a circle) is contained in this delta. You also know that it is not outside of this delta.  This constrains the problem considerably.

   *For example, if the change in lat and long is 10 for your distance then a location at (100,100) your box would be defined by (95,95) and (105,105) values for lat and long.*
3. Write a query that looks at each element (from lowest id) and searches for other elements (with greater id to avoid duplicates) within the the delta of lat and log and save this to a temporary table.
4. Iterate over that table and do a full calculation to see if it is within the circle (not the box) of your distance.